# Deepcopy a simple Python object

Tags: python, deep-copy

I have an object which defines a `__deepcopy__` method. I would like a function that will deepcopy it *not* by the method given by it, but in the default way that objects of the class `object` are copied.

How could I do that? I think I could try to code it but there are probably many "gotchas" I won't be thinking of.

The reason I'm doing it is because I have an object class which implements a `__deepcopy__` method, and that method checks for some condition, and in some cases it will deepcopy the object in a certain way, and in other cases it will deepcopy in the default `object` way.

Answer (score 4):

You basically need to override the existing `__deepcopy__` method, which means temporarily setting the object's class to something different  -- whether that's acceptable essentially depends on whether the "`__deepcopy__` override" needs to affect only one, "top-level" object (in which case the kludge's probably OK), or if there are many objects of that class in the graph you're copying, in which case it's quite a mess.  Which case obtains?

Comment: I think there would be multiple objects of that class in the tree, sorry. Also, I am scared by the thought of changing the object's class!